# How to show Iplmage format on the GUI of C++ instead of showing it in another windows?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++builder

I'm trying to display the output image onto the C++ interface instead of creating another window to display the image. 
For example:    cvNameWindow("Window A",0);
                cvShowImage("Window A", imgA);
This will create an window and display the imgA on it.
My question is that can i display my imgA onto my C++ interface together with all my other button and textbox.
I'm using Borland C++ Builder 6 and OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, since it's open source, you can have a look at the cvShowImage implementation for Windows [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/src/highgui/window_w32.cpp).

My C++ Builder memories are a bit fuzzy but I guess you can skip all the CvWindow calls and use any control's (a PaintBox?) GetDeviceContext() to its the DC and GetClientRect() to get its size.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the IplImage to a Graphics::TBitmap with [this](http://devkyy.tistory.com/174). Then you can draw it as [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21859).